# Moving all files in a directory except for a specific few on RPi

Tags: linux

I have a program that I'm trying to write that will remotely update all of the files within a directory on a remote Raspberry Pi 4b. I know the names of the files that need to stay in the directory and these will never change. I've seen examples where a command a la:
`mv * !(filetostay) /destination`
will skip over a specific file that is desired to stay, but is there a way to execute that when there are several files that I want to skip?
Additionally, the files are not consecutive alphabetically or any other way that I can think of, I just know the names of the files.

I have tried executing the following:
`shopt -s extglob`
`mv * !(file1|file2) destination`
but the RPi doesn't like the syntax as it says
`mv: cannot move 'destination' to a subdirectory of itself, 'destination/destination'`
`mv: warning: source directory 'destination' specified more than once`
`mv: cannot stat 'file1': No such file or directory`
`mv: cannot stat 'file2': No such file or directory`

Comment: something like `cd localDir ; ls -1 | grep -vf /path/to/excludeList.txt | awk '{print "mv " $0 "/alt/path/dir"}'| /bin/bash` is a place to start. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
mv !(file1|file2) destination
```

The extra asterisk means the list of every non-hidden file in pwd

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).